# Python 'for' loop skips code

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I have a `for` loop that skips the code in the loop when more than one item is in the range.  If I enter `1` for the number of students it will print that student's name and score to the file.  If I enter more than `1` for the number of students, it will skip the code in the `for` loop.

What gives?  Here is the code:

```
def main():
    num_students = int(input("How many students? "))
    students_file = open('students_file.txt', 'w')
    for count in range(1 - num_students + 1):
        print('Enter the data for student ',count, sep='')
        name = input('Name: ')
        score = input('Score: ')
        students_file.write(name + '\n')
        students_file.write(score + '\n')
        print()
    students_file.close()
    print("The student's data is written to students_file.txt")

main()
```

Comment: `1 - (2) + 1 = 0`; `range(0)` is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for count in range (1 - num_studnets + 1)`

You are using a dash, you should be using a comma. If you enter `num_students = 2`, for example, you get:

```
for count in range(0)
```

which will not run the for loop. (We get 0 because 1 - 2 + 1 = 0).

Correct example: `for count in range(1, num_students+1)`

Comment: That's an oversight on my part.  I knew this.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a *zero or negative end value* to `range()`, so it'll stop immediately; an empty range is produced:

```
>>> list(range(0))
[]
>>> list(range(-1))
[]
```

That's because you subtract `num_students` from 1, then add 1 at the end. So 1 - 2 + 1 is 0, 1 - 3 + 1 is -1, etc.

If you wanted to loop for `num_students` iterations, then just do so:

```
for count in range(num_students):
```

or if you wanted to produce the numbers 1 through to `num_students` inclusive, you could include a *starting value* and loop to `num_students + 1`:

```
for count in range(1, num_students + 1):
```

or just add 1 to `count` inside the loop:

```
for count in range(num_students):
    print('Enter the data for student', count + 1)
    name = input('Name: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index is calculated wrongly:

If your `num_students` is equal to one, your range receives `1-1+1` = 1. If your `num_students` is equal to two, your range receives `1-2+1` = 0. Any other `num_students` higher than two returns a negative number.

Shouldn't you just use `for i in range(num_students)` instead?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
for count in range(1 - num_students + 1):
```

specially here (1 - num_students + 1)
this is a math not a range loop

if you entered 1 student it will be like this ( 1 - 1 + 1 ) = 1
then the program will enter the loop

but if you entered 4 it will be like this ( 1 - 4 + 1 ) = -2
the program will not enter the loop for negative number

to fix it just replace "-" with ","
and you did correct when you added "+ 1" at the end to get the correct range

Comment: looking back on this question 8 years in the future, It seems like a dumb question now.  But at the time, it was a mystery.  Time changes all.   :-)